# Filter dictionary with values of different types

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, filter

I am trying to filter dictionary by value (dictionary with different data types), but got the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I want to get all records corresponding to 'YALE' value in my dictionary.

This is my code:

```
dataset = {
    'timeseires': array([[
        [ -5.653222,   7.39066 ,  20.651941, 4.07861 ,-11.752331, -34.611312],
        [ -5.653222,   7.39066 ,  20.651941, 4.07861 ,-11.752331, -34.611312]
    ]]),
    'site': array(['YALE', 'KKI'], dtype='<U8')
}

dataset = data.tolist()
 
def filter(pairs):
    key, value = pairs
    filter_key = 'site'
    if key == filter_key and value == 'YALE':
        return True
    else:
        return False
         
final_dic = dict(filter(filter, dataset.items()))
print(final_dic)
```

The expected output:

```
> dataset = {
>         'timeseires': array([[
>             [ -5.653222,   7.39066 ,  20.651941, 4.07861 ,-11.752331, -34.611312]
>         ]]),
>         'site': array(['KKI'], dtype='<U8')
>     }
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output for this input?

Comment: `dataset = data.tolist()` overwrites the first `dataset = { … }`. Please clarify what you actually have.

Comment: `def filter(pairs): ...` overwrites the builtin function `filter`. This doesn't make sense: `filter(filter, dataset.items())`

Comment: Please make sure the example is actually reproducible before posting, and provide the expected result.

Comment: `array =='YALE'` gives an array boolean result, which cannot be used in an `if` statement.  Test the pieces of your conditions before trying to make something complicated.

Comment: Did you mean to have a 3d array in timeseries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output given, it seems like your task is to extract the `'timeseries'` value corresponding to the index of the `'YALE'`.

This code should do the trick:

```
def filter_dictionary_by_value(dataset, value):
    index_value = np.where(dataset['site'] == value)[0]
    filtered_timeseries = dataset['timeseries'][index_value]
    

    filtered_dict = {
        'timeseries': filtered_timeseries,
        'site': np.array([value], dtype='<U8')
    }
```

If this wasn't what you were expecting please be more specific in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your expected output, you could do something like this using `dict` comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

filtered_indices = np.where(dataset["site"] == "YALE")[0].tolist()
dataset = {k: np.delete(v, filtered_indices) for k, v in dataset.items()}
```

```
{'timeseires': array([  7.39066 ,  20.651941,   4.07861 , -11.752331, -34.611312,
        -5.653222,   7.39066 ,  20.651941,   4.07861 , -11.752331,
       -34.611312]), 'site': array(['KKI'], dtype='<U8')}
```

Comment: The timeseries you have is still the whole initial array. I believe OP has a 3d timeseries instead of a 2d timeseries.. so it becomes abit hectic